# Outlook won't accept my certificate for OMS (sms messaging service)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, ssl, sms

I have implemented an OMS service. Outlook requires that OMS uses https, so I have also created a self-signed cert with SelfSSL.exe, and imported the cert to my computer (Trusted Root Certification Authorities and Trusted Publishers). With IE, I can access the service fine, without errors concerning non-verified cert. But Outlook will give me the following error message:

```
Outlook did not receive response from the Web service because of a problem connecting to the server. Try again later.
```

As far as I can find out, this propably indicates that there's something wrong with the cert, and Outlook can't establish ssl connection to the server. I have tested everything on my local environment, and everything works fine (IIS 7.5, production is IIS6). Everything also works fine when I call the https service from my own code. But for some reason, Outlook just don't want to co-operate with the service.

I know there are special rules for certs in Outlook, like some services can't be used at all with self-signed certs, and some require that the cert be valid for only a year or so. I have taken this into account, but still can't get this to work.

Has anyone encountered this problem before, and could perhaps give an advice?

Comment: Are you sure the cert is the problem? Outlook could be attempting to communicate with the OMS but your implementation is returning an unexpected message.

Comment: This should give "Unknown error" or similiar message in Outlook. I have found some information that suggests that you can only use self-signed cert with localhost environment. I'll try to remember to update this question when I get the real cert to play around with.